# how to replace multiple strings with replace method at once without making more string objects

Tags: java

I got a string test `"{\"userName\": \"<userName>\",\"firstName\": \"<firstName>\",\"lastName\": \"<lastName>\"}"`. what I want is that I want to replace things in angular brackets with dynamic values. Sample code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String toBeReplaced0 = "alpha";
        String toBeReplaced1 = "beta";
        String toBeReplaced2 = "gama";

        String test = "{\"userName\": \"<userName>\",\"firstName\": \"<firstName>\",\"lastName\": \"<lastName>\"}";

    }

}
```

Now in this code I want to replace `<userName>` with `alpha`, `<firstName>` with `beta`, `<lastName>` with `gama` at once without making multiple string objects. This is not a homework question. `test` string can have more angular elements in it to be filled with dynamic values. How can I do this with replace method or any thing else..

Comment: Why do you want to avoid multiple String objects? The JVM is very good at handling them efficiently.

Comment: to avoid multiple string objects in pool. memory critical application.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matcher.appendReplacement could be an option. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String toBeReplaced0 = "alpha";
    String toBeReplaced1 = "beta";
    String toBeReplaced2 = "gama";
    String test = "{\"userName\": \"<userName>\",\"firstName\": \"<firstName>\",\"lastName\": \"<lastName>\"}";
    System.out.println(findAndReplace(test,toBeReplaced0,toBeReplaced1,toBeReplaced2));        
}
public static String findAndReplace(String original, String... replacments){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^<]*>");
    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(original);
    // count the matches
    int count = 0;
    while (m1.find()){
        count++; 
    }
    // if matches count equals replacement params length replace in the given order
    if(count == replacments.length){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(original);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int i = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, replacments[i]);
            i++;
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);            
        return sb.toString();
    }
    //else return original
    return original;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's JSON, I'd prefer to use [a JSON library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) to dynamically construct the resultant string and mitigate any possible syntactic errors.

If you really want to use `String.replaceAll()` or similar, I wouldn't expect that to be a problem in the above limited scope. Simply chain together your calls (e.g. [see this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm))

Note that strings are *immutable*, and as such you can't easily do this without creating new string objects. If that's really a concern, perhaps you need to modify an array of chars (but that will be a non-trivial task when substituting multiple strings of varying lengths differing from their placeholders).

Simply:

```
String result = orig.replace("<userName>", "replacement");
```

(not forgetting that strings are immutable and so you have to use the result returned from this call)

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with the [StringTemplate library](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4). With your example works out of the box:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>ST4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    // Given
    final ST template = new ST("{\"userName\": \"<userName>\",\"firstName\": \"<firstName>\",\"lastName\": \"<lastName>\"}");
    template.add("userName", "alpha");
    template.add("firstName", "beta");
    template.add("lastName", "gamma");
    // When
    final String result = template.render();
    // Then
    Assert.assertEquals("{\"userName\": \"alpha\",\"firstName\": \"beta\",\"lastName\": \"gamma\"}", result);
```